# Linear Mixed Model non normal residuals large dataset (I.e., 1500 datapoints)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, normality-assumption, likert

I have a relatively large dataset (around 1500 data points) comprised by around 90 subjects where each subject is measured 14 times on a likert scale -1 to 5-.

When I analyze the data with the lmer function in R, the residuals do not look normal at all (just in the +-1 sd). If this was a traditional linear regression there would be -a priori- no problem: there are quite many references pointing towards the robustness of linear regression to departures from normality in such large datasets as the Central Limit Theorem seems to apply. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any paper/reference pointing towards the robustness of linear mixed models in large sample sizes to departures from normality/homoscedasticity.

Do you know any?